# Vue.js, Bootstrap, custom _rowVariant color (custom.scss)

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, sass, bootstrap-vue

I would like to be able to add a custom color as a background to my table in vue

This is my .vue file:

```
<template>
....
  <b-table small :fields="fields" :items="items">
    <template #cell(name)="data">
      <b>{{ data.value.name }}</b>
    </template>
    ....    
  </b-table>
....
<template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      items: [
          { name: { name: '....', url: '....' }, utility: '....', icon: '../assets/.....png', _rowVariant: 'light' },
          { name: { name: '....', url: '....' }, utility: '....', icon: '../assets/.....png', _rowVariant: 'success' },
          { name: { name: '....', url: '....' }, utility: '....', icon: '../assets/.....png', _rowVariant: 'danger' },
          { name: { name: '....', url: '....' }, utility: '....', icon: '../assets/.....png', _rowVariant: 'custom-one' }
      ],
      tableVariants: ['primary', 'secondary', 'info', 'danger', 'warning', 'success', 'light', 'dark','custom-one', 'custom-two', 'custom-three' ],
..........
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import '../scss/custom.scss';
.........
</style>
```

As you can see i'm trying to import from  the $theme-colors declaring within the Array tableVariant.

my custom.scss file:

```
$purple:  #6f42c1 !default;
$porpora: #75151e !default;
$orange:  #fd7e14 !default;


$theme-colors:(
  "custom-one": $orange,
  "custom-two": $purple,
  "custom-three": $porpora
);

@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

How can I add a _rowVariant custom color?
Thanks!

Comment: Any reason why you're importing your `custom.scss` file in a component, instead of globally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<b-table>` element results into a `<table>` element with a class of `b-table` (and some other bootstrap specific classes). By default, this element does not have a `background-color`, except for the case of `:dark="true"`, which applies `background-color: #343a40;` to it.

Which means

```
.b-table {
  background-color: red;
}
```

...will work.

Change `red` to your desired color. If your color is dark, pass `:dark="true"` to `<b-table>` which will change text colors and cell/row border colors accordingly.

Also, if you only want this on one particular table, give it an id or a class and use that selector to make the rule apply only to that element (the above will apply it to all `<b-table>` elements).

Note this does not interfere with your ability to style rows and cells using [`_cellVariant` and/or `_rowVariant`](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#items-record-data).

---

If you want to go down the route of defining extra bootstrap color variants, here's how to do it:

**customized-bootstrap.scss**

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";

// removes the colors, if you don't use them
$colors: map-remove($colors,
  "blue", "indigo", "purple", "pink", "red", "orange", "yellow",
  "green", "teal", "cyan", "white", "gray", "gray-dark"
);

// adds custom colors, should you want any:
$colors: (
  "orange": #f50,
  "red": #BC2E2E,
  "green": #8CB439,
  "yellow": #DEC648
);

// removes theme-colors you don't want:
$theme-colors: map-remove($theme-colors,
  "warning", "info", "light", "dark"
);

// adds theme-colors you want. Note this this is not assigned
// it is merged with the difference between defaults and the ones removed above
// so, for example, `$secondary`, `$danger` will still be present.
$theme-colors: (
  "primary": #f50,
  "light": #DDDEE1,
  "dark": #15161a,
  "badass": #BADA55
);

// import the functionality you want (and remove the stuff you don't want).
// from `~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap`, except the first three 
// `functions`, `variables` and `mixins`, 
// which you already imported and used above

@import "~bootstrap/scss/root";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/type";

//... all the way down to `~bootstrap/scss/print`
```

Obviously, in your `main.(js|ts)` you have to replace

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
```

with

```
import './path/to/customized-bootstrap.scss'
```

Now you can use `var(--badass)` on any element of your app, it will result into `#BADA55`.
For example, if you provide a row with: `_rowVariant: "badass"`, it will apply the class `table-badass` to all the cells of that row and, in your CSS, you should have:

```
.table-badass {
  background-color: var(--badass);
  color: var(--light);
}
```

Comment: I tried to apply the color to the b-table class and it works.
But I would like to know if there is a way to manage the colors of the different rows, and not of the whole table. Thanks

Comment: @Pietro, last, but not least, asking additional questions in answer comments is *off-topic* on [SO]. If answered, such questions don't benefit from indexing and future [SO] users with the same question won't be able to benefit from the answer. In short, by asking in comments you're being selfish. Be generous and ask it separately, if it hasn't been asked before.